# Loading different views into a custom view dynamically

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, nsview, custom-view

I've an application that performs a multi-step process. Each step is implemented as a `NSView` subclass and I want to navigate between the different views. I'm trying this by implementing a custom view and then loading different views into the custom view I made. Is this the right way to do it?
What is the best approach to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

until you use only one view your approach is correct. If you load a view into your custom view and remove it before loading another view ,i feel it's ok. make sure that you use only one view to accomplish your task which i feel is possible.

all the best.if you find a better approach plz update

TNQ